# How to point my subdomain in the htaccess file to the directory where the WordPress index.php is present?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, polylang

I'm trying to set up multilingual WordPress site using the PolyLang plugin. My website will have 3 languages - Ukrainian, Russian and English. Ukrainian default.

In the URL settings of polylang, there is an option to select a language by subdomain. The idea is that the URLs looks like this: “example.com” - is the default Ukrainian language main page of the site. “ru.example.com” - is Russian language, and “en.example.com” is English.

On the hosting, I have already created two subdomains ru and en. In the server root directory, there are 2 folders with the appropriate names. My question is whether it is possible and how to configure the .htaccess file like this: when a visitor gets to the subdomain page - the server returns not the file in the corresponding folder, but the index.php file located in the root.

I have already tried to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ru\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [P]
```

And that's not worked. Not any results, just like nothing changed.

Here is full .htaccess file from the root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ru\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [P]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Maybe I need to create and write .htaccess files in subdomain folders...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you just mean that it calls the main wordpress site, so in affect you access your main site with ru.example.com and get the same site as www.exmaple.com, but with the language translated?

Comment: You could point the subdomains at the route when you set them up (vhost / cpanel etc.).

Then get the language from the domain name and use it to set the language.  As for the database side of things so it know the site, that's a trickier one.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use these subdomains, and forward to your main www site, but use the referer (being ru.exmaple.com etc.) to get the language you need to set.